# How to add html on each of start and end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to add html on each of start and end of an array

Here is my array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

what I want to do was add `<span>` at the start of the array and `</span>` at the end so become like this

```
<span>1</span>, <span>2</span>,...
```

How I can do this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `echo magic($array, 'span');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the following,

```
<?php
    $demo = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    $string = '';

    foreach ($demo as $item) {
        $string .= '<span>' . $item . '</span>,';
    }

    echo $string;
```

Ends up with,

```
<span>1</span>,<span>2</span>,<span>3</span>,<span>4</span>,<span>5</span>,
```